# Exchange key between two clients through a server

Tags: security, protocols, diffie-hellman

I have a problem about exchange a key between two clients through a server.

But I don't want the server being able to intercept the key or make a MitM.

What method can I use to avoid this problem?

Comment: You've already named one in your tags — [the Diffie–Hellman key exchange protocol](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diffie%E2%80%93Hellman_key_exchange) is one such method. Read the Wikipedia article for details, and information on other key exchange protocols.

Comment: Sure, but if I use Diffie-Helmann through a server it's different. Because the server can simulate a MitM attack and the 2 clients don't notice a problem. What can I do to prevent Mitm?